# Preventing team from editing checkboxes after due date has passed on google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

My team has to perform some daily standard tasks. I've made a list of tasks and a datesheet and have added checkboxes. 
I want to prevent my team members from checking those boxes after the due date so I can ask them. 
Link to sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i9WUlhq6KtLy6Lv8YpkfOBu2rjhitPbs0YUZN8mD1tk/edit?usp=sharing

Example: Prevent members from checking boxes in column C when date C1 is gone, column D when D1 is gone and so on.

It'll be great if you guys can help.

Comment: "It'll be great if you guys can help." I've read your question; what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Cells From Being Edited Based on Date - Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53104808/prevent-cells-from-being-edited-based-on-date-google-sheets)

Comment: There is an expectation that you will have done some research before you ask a question. Have you read [Automatically locking a range (column) as each date passes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43811562/1330560) or [Locking cells in Google Sheets at a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625064/1330560), or [Lock a sheet when date in column > 24 hours: Google Sheets - Scripteditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53011123/1330560) (slight variation to this topic but relevant), or [How to lock a cell based on date in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52394/196152).

Comment: I've tried everything but it's still not working. One person I've shared this sheet with is able to edit column C even when the date has passed.
 Can you guys please write the code?

Comment: "I've tried everything but it's still not working" If you've written some code, please edit your question to include it. Your spreadsheet doesn't include any code at all; you could/should also include your code in your spreadsheet.

Comment: "Can you guys please write the code?" There was never a sentence more likely to ensure that no-one will reply to your question. This is not a coding service and you've shown no indication of having tried to solve your own problem or even having researched it. If you have a specific coding problem (and it does sound like you have), then people are very keen to try and help you solve it. Include your code, even the stuff that didn't work.